# Why is there no driver output listed for this host bridge?

Tags: drivers, pci

When I run lspci on my Intel machine, I see a driver in use:

```bash
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
        Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
```

The skl_uncore is managing this device.

When I run lspci on my AMD machine, there is no driver in use listed for the host bridge:

```bash
$ sudo lspci -v -s 00:00.0
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
        Flags: fast devsel
```